# Data brushing in MS excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using MS Excel 2019 and I'm trying to copy only coordinates of specific selected data points in a scatter plot. Does anyone know whether this is possible. Any possible workaround if possible? My input to the Excel scatter plot are basically `x` and `y` coordinates in all 4 quadrants.

Data used:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| -2 | -10 |
| 39 | -8 |
| 56 | 10 |
| 34 | 8 |
| -89 | -8 |
| 43 | 5 |
| -9 | 4 |
| 45 | 3 |
| 67 | -16 |
| -87 | -19 |

Scatter plot:

[image: SCATTER PLOT FROM EXCEL]

What I need is  basically select specific points in the first quadrant as mentioned in the red circle from the Excel plot itself and export the selected data points value to separate table. The mouse pointer hover on each point shows its value, but I can't capture multiple data points value using mouse.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, add relevant data and show what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about creating a helper column, which only allows coordinates in the first quadrant? You can achieve this, using following formulas:

```
in C2 : =IF(AND(A2>=0;B2>=0);A2;0)
in D2 : =IF(AND(A2>=0;B2>=0);B2;0)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, well i've migrated to python and R for these kind of tasks, so prolly wont be using excel for this.